# MySQL current_insert_id()? (Not last_insert_id())

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, insert-id

I am inserting a row with a char column for a hash based on (among other things) the row's auto id.

I know I can insert it, fetch the insert_id, calculate the hash, and update it.

Does anyone know of a way to do this in a single query?  You would need the rows insert_id at the time of insert.  Is that completely impossible, or is there something like current_insert_id()...

Thanks!

Comment: I am curious, why would you ever need a column with a hash generated from the rows key ?

Comment: In this case, it's actually not a hash, but a semi readable public key, made of the row key in base 36, appended to some other stuff.  It's used as the public key in forms and other places where I need a unique key to id the row, but don't want to expose the actual row id, or show a predictable pattern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there's no function in MySQL that gives you the `current_insert_id()`.

The only way to get a generated ID value from an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field in MySQL is to do the INSERT and then call `last_insert_id()`.  So your plan of doing a separate UPDATE to calculate the hash is probably what you'll have to do.

I can think of two other alternatives:

- Generate the unique value yourself before the INSERT with some other mechanism besides the `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  For example, see the [`UUID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function.

  ```
  SET @id = SELECT UUID();
  INSERT INTO MyTable (id, hash) VALUES (@id, hash(@id...));
  ```
- Don't include the ID in your hash calculation.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way that I know of to do it in MySQL in one query, but you could do something like this in your server-side scripting language of choice:

```
<?php

$query = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'MyTable'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$next_id = $row['Auto_increment'];

?>
```

...which gives you the id to incorporate in your SQL.

EDIT: I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469009/can-you-access-the-auto-increment-value-in-mysql-within-one-statement) which may be helpful.

Comment: This is susceptible to a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the next-to-be-used value from the `information_schema`.`TABLES` table, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column there.  (You might be setting yourself up for a race condition?)

Comment: Yes, this would be susceptible to a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

When I do inserts I do something like this:

`INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES (data1,data2);SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`

and just run the query like I was fetching data. In VB.NET the syntax is (assuming you have the MySql.Data.MySqlClient .dll):

```
Dim sql As String = "[sql string above]"
Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = YourRetrieveDataFunction(sql)

dr.Read()
yourObjectInstance.ID = dr(0)
dr.Close
```

It's technically two queries, but only one hit on the database :)

Comment: Eli wants the id that is *about* to be inserted, not the one that's just been inserted.

Comment: hmm... SELECT whatever, (SELECT id+1 FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS newid  .... ? i dunno if this actually works

Comment: FWIW, querying the top id+1 is susceptible to a race condition.  Don't use it if you have more than one concurrent client.