# How to get the id of an inserted row ON insert?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I would like to create a unique hash of an AUTO-INCREMENT field while inserting that row. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`hash`,`salt`) VALUES (MD5(CONCAT(`id`,`salt`)),'1234789687');
```

Is it possible to use the AUTO-INCREMENTED id of the row WHILE I'm inserting? Or do I have to wait until it's inserted to grab it via PHP or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no- it is not possible. If your db has low transaction volume, then concurrency may not be an issue to use something similar to `select max()` (susceptible to interference) : [Can you access the auto increment value in MySQL within one statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469009/can-you-access-the-auto-increment-value-in-mysql-within-one-statement)

I would follow the insert in php with an update

```
update `table`
set `hash` = MD5(CONCAT(`id`,`salt`))
where `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but really doubt that this is possible. I see why you would want to thought...It's not so elegant to insert the row, then immediately update it.

I would consider if you really need to store the hash in the DB or if you can calculate it during the select:

SELECT MD5(CONCAT(`id`,`salt`)) FROM table WHERE ...