# insert autoincreament value into another column as well

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like:

```
id | link
---------
1  | abc
2  | asd
```

and link column should contain **id**, example: `1-abc`. id is autoincreament.

I have this sql:

```
insert into table(link) values('abc');
```

should I update back the table, or is there a solution to do it in one query?

Comment: Do you really need this data stored in the database?  Because you could just as easily select this out when you query the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the id of an inserted row ON insert?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465890/how-to-get-the-id-of-an-inserted-row-on-insert)

Comment: you could use a trigger on the database if you 're running mysql

Comment: You could replace the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column with a simulated sequence, using [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on mysql only and is the kind of inserting values from one table to another table-

```
INSERT INTO tablename (`link`) SELECT concat(`AUTO_INCREMENT`,'-','abc') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourdbname' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'
```

this will add your id infront of your table, i don't know whether it will work  or not other than mysql, it works fine in mysql