# Laravel auto-increment on non-primary field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

There is my migration. I want `id` field being auto-incremented  but not primary. Is it possible? This migration throws an exception `Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

```
Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('project_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('model_id'); 
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->dropPrimary('id');

    $table->foreign('project_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('projects')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->primary(['project_id', 'model_id']);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not `Laravel` error. you can't have two auto increment column in mysql table. (of course if you are using mysql) but I think none of any relational database gives you ability to have two auto increment columns.

But there is another way to do that.
look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824439/how-to-create-two-auto-increment-column-in-mysql) question

Comment: But `id` is only auto increment column in my case

Comment: i have the same problem, id should be auto incrementing column but i want to use another column as primary key. did you find any solution? @fiter

Comment: @siri sorry, nope

Comment: It is a Laravel error because it adds the primary key without asking for the increments field. The question is how to do it with migration, not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Laravel error but a MySQL error. As the error message says: `it must be defined as a key`. You are dropping the `primaryKey` constraint on the `id` column. You should try setting it as an index.

try the following `$table->unsignedInteger('id')->index()->autoIncrement();`. This will make it an AI integer and also an index but not a PK.

Comment: unfortunately I'm getting an error in this case : `Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (SQL: alter table 'tests' add primary key 'tests_project_id_model_id_primary'('project_id', 'model_id'))`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the easiest way to use raw SQL. Another methods I found didn't work.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD INDEX `id` (`id`);');
});
```