# add auto incrementing id in a table with existing primary key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

I am trying to add the auto-incrementing id to the existing table with its existing primary key

here is my code

**initial migration for the table code**

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->string('ISBN')->index();
            $table->string('name')->index();
            $table->string('publisher');
            $table->string('level_levelName')->index();
            $table->string('provider_providerName')->index();
            $table->string('category_categoryName')->index();
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->primary('ISBN');
            $table->foreign('provider_providerName')->references('providerName')->on('providers')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('level_levelName')->references('levelName')->on('levels')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_categoryName')->references('categoryName')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

        });
    }
```

**add auto incrementint id to existing table code**

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
        });
    }
```

what I am trying to do is add an auto-incrementing id to this existing table 
but it is giving me this error

```
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary keys defined (SQL: alter table 
`books` add `id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key)
```

Please can somebody help me? I don't want to remove table's primary key, I just want to add another auto-incrementing id which is not a primary key but it can be `unique key`

Comment: You can't do it with `bigIncrements`. That will attempt to set it to primary

Comment: the how am i going to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Laravel error. You can't have two auto increment column in mysql table.

However you can add to your model, get the biggest value of your field in the database and +1 then insert.

Other solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824439/how-to-create-two-auto-increment-column-in-mysql)

Comment: I want to do it with laravel, sir

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `bigIncrements` as that will attempt to create it as a primary key. You can try this instead:

```
$table->bigInteger('id', true, true)->index();
```

Per the definition of `bigInteger` (`public function bigInteger($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false))` The second value is for auto increment and the third is signed/unsigned. From [Mysql Innodb: Autoincrement non-Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086324/mysql-innodb-autoincrement-non-primary-key), the auto-increment key must be indexed.

Comment: great, you may short it to : $table->->unsignedBigInteger('columnName', true)->index();

Comment: even not working here is the error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (SQL: alter table \`books\` add \`id\` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key)`

Comment: How odd. There's no primary on any of the function definitions, even going all the way through. You did remove the bigIncrements line, correct?

Comment: yes @aynber i removed it , see `$table->unsignedBigInteger('id',true)->index();`

Comment: No idea, then. You might need to do with manually with `DB::statement("alter table \`books\` add \`id\` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment, add index id_idx(id)");`