# how to have more than 1 auto increement in myphpadmin/mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to know how can I add more than one auto increment in the same table. Usually I use sequence for this issue but in myphpadmin, I don't have sequence so I have do it in other way.

Below is the example I'm trying to achieve. which is have ID, SecondID and thirdID all auto increment. I cant change the structure to have only one auto increment due to many issues so i need to follow this structure

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  ID              INT    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  section  VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL, 
  secondID           INT   AUTO_INCREMENT,
  thirdID           INT   AUTO_INCREMENT,
  message  VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER testing After INSERT
ON test
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO test(secondID) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID());
END;
```

I tried using the Trigger but im getting error saying

"#1442 - Can't update table 'test' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
"

Can anyone provide me with suggestion or approach to solve this issue

Thank you

Comment: I can't imagine how/why secondid and thirdid values could differ from id so why not make them the same using a trigger or generated column. -or perhaps the published table is not representative?

Comment: Unsolvable. You cannot have more than one AUTO_INCREMENT column in the table. From the other side I strongly doubt that you really need in AUTO_INCREMENT for these columns. Post the task itself, describe why you decide that you need in AI for these secondary columns - I think that your logic is not correct, and the task must be solved by another way. XY-problem.

Comment: @P.Salmon Neither trigger nor generated column can help. BEFORE trigger - AI value not exists yet. AFTER trigger - AI accessible, but the trigger cannot update the table. Generated column - cannot refer to AI column.

Comment: Im planning to use Trigger but if you can guide me how to do it it will be great

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create two auto increment columns in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824439/how-to-create-two-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

[There can be only one AUTO_INCREMENT column per table...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html)

This is how MySQL is implemented. You may want to look into creating triggers if you absolutely need this. Another option is incrementing it from your application logic.

Comment: can you guide me into how to create a Trigger for this issue