# How to set username using id in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a database table in mysql

```
create table userstable
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(80) not null,
    username  varchar(80) not null,
    primary key(id)
);
```

How to add new row in mysql database, so that username will be 'name'+('id'*100)

Example :

```
ID  name    username

1   A       A100
2   B       B200
3   C       C300
4   user    user400
```

Comment: You need to use triggers for that. Create a AFTER INSERT trigger for that table

Comment: Just to confirm what's obvious from the DDL: You are fine with duplicates in `username`. e.g. `(1,A1,A1100)` and `(11,A,A1100)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need trigger for that process. Create the following trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER username_change 
BEFORE INSERT ON userstable 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 SET NEW.username = CONCAT(NEW.name,(NEW.id*100)); 
END
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO userstable (id,name, username) VALUES (2, 'B', CONCAT(name,(id*100)));
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,it's work, but can i solve this using subquery  / query without using trigger?

Comment: @Divyang - Check the insert query I have given.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a trigger or update the field after insertion.  A similar question provides more insight:

[Can you access the auto increment value in MySQL within one statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469009/can-you-access-the-auto-increment-value-in-mysql-within-one-statement)

Answer (score 0):

As @ArunKrish correctly pointed out, you may use `TRIGGER` to update the data as part of the insert. Another option is to use view:

```
CREATE VIEW v1 AS 
 SELECT id,name,CONCAT(name,id*100) AS username FROM userstable;
```

You may also use the query as-is, without view:

```
SELECT id,name,CONCAT(name,id*100) AS username FROM userstable;
```