# MySQL : How to set the starting value of auto-increment field?

Tags: php, mysql

For example,
there is a table `articles`,it has these fields:

```
id
title
content
slug
```

`id` field is auto-increment, the value starts from `1`.

**Question:**
I want to set `slug` field to be auto-increment, and the value starts from `10000`,how to do it?

Comment: Your `articles` table can have only one auto increment column.  If we make `slug` auto increment, then `id` would lose that condition.

Comment: You can use a trigger , to update slug field to ID + 10000

Comment: If slug is simply ID+10000, whats the point in duplicating the data in the database?

Comment: you can have separate table with storing last autoincrement id for all your tables you want to have separate autoincrement field and use it to substitute in before insert trigger and set new value of autoincrement id.

But honestly - I doubt you need it. What do you want to achieve ? What's the problem you are trying to resolve ?

Comment: Please check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469009/can-you-access-the-auto-increment-value-in-mysql-within-one-statement

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want 2 fields to be auto incremented? They are going to have the same values, even if one starts from 10000..

Example:

```
id | title | content | slug
---| ------|---------|------
 1 |                  10000
 2 |                  10001
 3 |                  10001
 . |                  .
 . |                  .
 n |                  n + 10000 - 1
```

All you have to do is:

```
UPDATE articles SET slug = id + (10000 - 1) WHERE id = 'any id here..'
```