# MySQL : How to query two tables sequentially?

Tags: mysql, laravel

For example,
there are two tables `articles_1` and `articles_2`，they have the same fields:

```
id
title
content
slug
```

When there is one table, I can query an article like this:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $article = Article::findOrFail($slug);

    return view('show', compact('article'));
}
```

Now there are two tables,I want to query an article,how to write the code?

Comment: If all the fields are same, can you describe why are you using two tables ?

Comment: Perhaps you should address the feedback on [your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022462/mysql-how-to-set-the-starting-value-of-auto-increment-field) before asking more questions about the same problem.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thanks,I have voted your comment on that question,and I use string instead of auto-increament number.

Answer (score 1):

you could use UNION

```
$table1_items = \DB::table('articles_1')
            ->select(\DB::raw("id, title, content,slug"))

$table2_items  = \DB::table('software_items')
            ->select(\DB::raw("id, title, content,slug"))

$results = $table1_items->union($table2_items)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of creating View at Database layer itself. The View will use UNION to combine results from both table.