# Get current insert ID in one query

Tags: php, sql, pdo

In my query I need to insert the auto-increment ID of my row into another column.

I need the protonumber column to have 3 strings together, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the current lastinsertID and make it work.

Any ideas?

```
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO protonumbers (season,program,designer,brand,date,protonumber) VALUES (:season, :program, :designer, :brand, :date, :protonumber)');
        $last_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':season' => $season,
            ':program' => $program,
            ':designer' => $designer,
            ':brand' => $brand,
            ':date' => $date,
            ':protonumber' => "{$program}-{$season}-{$last_id}"
            ));
        $id = $db->lastInsertId('protoID');
```

Comment: You should make two query: after the 1st get ladtId and updatethe record  in the 2nd

Comment: Are you sure you need to store that? It's just three of your existing columns concatenated together. Seems like you could just produce it in that format when you query and output.

Comment: Yeah, I need to do that for other reasons. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Like @splash58 says. Assuming the insert ID you're referring to is the autoincrement ID of the record you just inserted, it doesn't exist until after the insert. You'll have to use a second update query.

Comment: You can also look into setting up an after insert trigger: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469009/can-you-access-the-auto-increment-value-in-mysql-within-one-statement

Comment: @Don'tPanic I prefer using triggers but some hosters don't allows them :(

Comment: @GabrielBalza generate it on fly: `SELECT protonumbers.* CONCAT(program,'-', season,'-' id_column_name) AS protonumber FROM protonumbers` (or any similar method to concat strings. this is for MySQL)

Comment: And `$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT...` don't make query, so you don't have `lastInsertId`

Comment: @Don't Panic I'm a little confused. Could you please show me how to update it with the 3 strings?

Comment: @bato3 how would it look?

Comment: @GabrielBalza what: `how would it look?` remove column `protonumber` from database and calculate it on the fly (example above) or make 2 queries: `INSERT` without correct `protonumber` value and `UPDATE` to fix them

Answer (score -2):

Use [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) from your SQL query.

Or

You can also use [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to get it using PHP.